# WordPress: Changing a drop down menu to a ul

Tags: php, wordpress, rows

I'm editing a WordPress theme named "Nova", and I'm relatively new to editing PHP.

Currently, the template uses drop-down menus for parent-child pages.

I would like to change that so rather than a drop down menu, there's just columns, with the top row being the parent page, and the rows directly beneath being the child pages.

How would I accomplish this? Thank you! ^_^

Comment: This doesn't really makes sense. Columns and rows implies a <table>, yet the title implies <ul>. Which one do you want? Also, without any code, there's nothing we can suggest...

Comment: I was using column/row merely to describe appearance. I simply need to know how the code would look inside the header to create a <ul> for the parent/child page links. I'm new at PHP and WordPress, so please bear with me.

Answer (score 0):

The markup is already there, it's just a matter of changing the stylesheet to change the appearance. You don't have to edit any code. Essentially, float the parents so they're next to each other, don't float the children so they appear vertically as a list does by default.

Comment: Could you be a little more descriptive with how I would do that? I sort of understand, but I need a little more. Thanks! :D

Comment: The exact CSS you need will depend on the markup your theme is generating. Can't be written for you without that.